# Не работает метод onBufferingUpdate при MediaPlayer, поставлненом на паузу

Tags: mediaplayer, android, многопоточность, загрузка, аудио

Здравствуйте.

В Android приложении использую MediaPlayer, на который ставлю слушатель событий OnBufferingUpdateListener, чтобы показывать процент загрузки аудио из сети. Но когда ставлю на паузу (выполняю метод pause()), перестает выполняться метод onBufferingUpdateonBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) из интерфейса OnBufferingUpdateListener, но загрузка в буфер продолжается, т.к. при выполнении метода start() процент загрузки может сразу стать 100%.

Как сделать, чтобы процент загрузки показывался, когда стоит пауза?